# How to rename bulk of jpg files to png using convert

Tags: bash, python, rename

Let's say I have a bunch of `.jpg` files which I want to convert to `.png`.  The file structure is as follow:

```
00-01.jpg 
00-02.jpg 
00-03.jpg 
00-04.jpg 
00-05a.jpg
00-05b.jpg
01-01.jpg 
01-02.jpg 
01-03a.jpg
01-03b.jpg
01-04a.jpg
01-04b.jpg
```

So now I want to rename  `00-01.jpg` to `ACDfff001.png`  then `00-02.jpg` to `ACDfff002.png` and so on.  However when I reach `00-05a.jpg` and `00-05b.jpg`  I want to name these as `ACDfff005a.png` respectively `ACDfff005b.png`.

The final result e.g should be as:

```
00-01.jpg  ->  ACDfff001.png
00-02.jpg  ->  ACDfff002.png
00-03.jpg  ->  ACDfff003.png
00-04.jpg  ->  ACDfff004.png
00-05a.jpg ->  ACDfff005a.png
00-05b.jpg ->  ACDfff005b.png
01-01.jpg  ->  ACDfff006.png
01-02.jpg  ->  ACDfff007.png
01-03a.jpg ->  ACDfff008a.png
01-03b.jpg ->  ACDfff008b.png
01-04a.jpg ->  ACDfff009a.png
01-04b.jpg ->  ACDfff009b.png
```

Is this possible in bash or python?

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Well I dont have a solution so if someone could assist me on this  would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a starting point; it assumes that the indexes only go up to 9; you'll have to extend it if that's not true.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

index=0
lastseq=
for file in *.jpg
do
  base=$(basename "$file" .jpg)
  lastchar=${base: -1:1}
  if [[ $lastchar =~ [[:digit:]] ]]
  then
    index=$((index + 1))
    newname=$(printf "ACDfff%03d" $index)
    lastseq=$lastchar
  else
    seclast=${base: -2:1}
    if [[ $seclast != $lastseq ]]
    then
      index=$((index + 1))
      lastseq=$seclast
    fi
    newname=$(printf "ACDfff%03d%s" $index $lastchar)
  fi
  echo mv "$file" "${newname}.png"
done
```

Comment: Perfectly!  This is what I needed.  Thank you very much